# How order the element in the case I pass them whit "get_object_or_404" from views

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I want to order "film" of "regista" ( `{% for film in regista.film_set.all %}` ) and "sequel" ( `{% for sequel in film.sequels.all %}` ) by "anno", but I don't know how I have to do....Thanks fo helping...

here models.py

```
class Anno( models.Model ):
    anno = models.CharField( max_length=4 )
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.anno
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Anni"

class Film( models.Model ):
    titolo = models.CharField( max_length=39 )
    trama = models.TextField( max_length=1000 )
    anno = models.ForeignKey( Anno )
    registi = models.ManyToManyField( Regista )
    generi = models.ManyToManyField( Genere_Film )
    sequels = models.ManyToManyField( "self", blank=True )
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.titolo + " " + self.trama
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Films"
```

here views.py

```
def film(request, id):
    film = get_object_or_404( Film, pk=id )
    return render_to_response('Film.html', { 'film': film })
```

here Film.html

```
{{ film.titolo }}
{% for generi in film.generi.all %}{{ generi.genere}}{% endfor %}
{{ film.anno }}
{{ film.trama }}
{% for regista in film.registi.all %}
  {{ regista.nome }} {{ regista.cognome }}
  {% for film in regista.film_set.all %}
    {{ film.titolo }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% for sequel in film.sequels.all %}
  {{ sequel.titolo }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `class Meta` , you can specify [`ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering)

```
class Anno( models.Model ):
    anno = models.CharField( max_length=4 )
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.anno
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Anni"
        ordering = ('anno', )
```